# How do I get a marker I have added to my leaflet map to be cleared once I choose another marker?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard, ggmap

I've added markers to my leaflet map based on user input, which comes from a selectInput on the page.
However, when the input changes, the original marker still remains on the map itself.
How do I get the marker to disappear once I change my input?

This is the UI code for my selectizeInput.

```
selectizeInput(inputId = "school",label = "Add marker", choices = data_new[order(data_new$Schools),]$Schools, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
```

This is my server code to observe the event when there is an input from the selectizeInput.

```
observeEvent(input$school,{

proxy <- leafletProxy('outputmap')
chosen_school <- data_new[data_new$Schools %in% input$school,]
proxy %>% setView(lng=as.numeric(chosen_school$lon), lat=as.numeric(chosen_school$lat), zoom=17) %>% addMarkers(lng=as.numeric(chosen_school$lon), lat=as.numeric(chosen_school$lat), popup= paste("School: ",chosen_school$Schools, "<br>", "Address: ",chosen_school$Address, "<br>", "Email: ",chosen_school$Email,"<br>","Bus No:", chosen_school$Bus_No),options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)) 

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your proxy you should first remove the marker before adding the selected ones. You can do this with the function `clearMarkers()` which removes all markers.

```
proxy %>% clearMarkers() %>% setView(lng=as.numeric(chosen_school$lon), lat=as.numeric(chosen_school$lat), zoom=17) %>% addMarkers(lng=as.numeric(chosen_school$lon), lat=as.numeric(chosen_school$lat), popup= paste("School: ",chosen_school$Schools, "<br>", "Address: ",chosen_school$Address, "<br>", "Email: ",chosen_school$Email,"<br>","Bus No:", chosen_school$Bus_No),options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE))
```

Another way is to add a `layerId` to your markers. Then you can use the function `removeMarker(~layerId)` to remove the markers that you don't want to show up.